# PHP скрипты запускаются через 4 минуты от запуска машины

Tags: php, php7

Всё стояло на PHP 5, запускается машина, CRON запускает скрипты.
Установил PHP 7.2 все работало когда проверял скрипты, перезапустил машину. Жду минуту, две, ничего не происходит, думал уже скрипты поломались, а нет, в логах пусто. Подождав еще 2 минуты скрипт запустился. Не поняв ситуацию я попробовал запустить различными способами после перезагрузки, результат аналогичен, 4 минуты после рестарта PHP тупо "спит".
Версия: `PHP 7.2.20-2+0~20190725.24+debian8~1.gbp69697c (cli) (built: Jul 25 2019 12:43:17) ( NTS )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение: установить пакет haveged